# C# using regex correctly

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to make a script (.dll) in c#.
I'm planning to read the value of a specific address, and if the value is not equal to a-z,A-Z,1-9, then i will do something.
I was trying to figure something out using Regex.
Here is my current result, wich is wrong obviously.

```
        public Main()
    {
        PlayerConnected += new Action<Entity>(player =>
        {
            try
            {
                Regex r = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
                Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("iw5mp").FirstOrDefault();
                Byte[] val = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(/*What should i do here?*/);
                var hProc = OpenProcess(0x1F0FFF, false, process.Id);
                int address = 0x1328d54;
                int BytesWritten = 0;

                ReadProcessMemory((int)hProc, address, val, val.Length, ref BytesWritten);
            }

            catch
            {
                //
            }


        });

    }
```

Comment: Tell us the input, what you are getting, and what you are expecting to get. We can't see what is being processed here.

Comment: What happens exactly?

Comment: Can't you just use reg.Match("your input").Value or reg.Match("your input").Success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this code (your problem isn't explained really good so I think this was your problem):

```
Match m = reg.Match("some input"); // To get the match
if (!m.Success) return; // (or throw error) Returns when the input string didn't match your pattern
Byte[] val = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(m.Value); // Gets the result of your match
```

You could also just do `Match m = Regex.Match("your input", "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")` to get your match

Your pattern will be a match with "" (empty), "a" and "ab3123" since any character of a-z, A-Z and 0-9 is allowed 0 or more times. Maybe you want to use + rather than * so empty string wouldn't be allowed. Use "^.+$" to allow any character or "^.+?$" to also allow empty strings.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But what should i put as 'your input'?
Here:
Match m = Regex.Match("your input", "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do here. You can also do PlayerConntected += (object sender, PlayerConnectedEventArgs e) => { ...  } instead of += new Action<Entity> and use the information of e (I don't know if PlayerConnectedEventArgs exists).

Comment: or I just noticed that you can also use player.XXX

Comment: Using a mod libary. :)